# How to Change the Class loader order to parent last in ManageModules using IBM JAVA API?

Tags: java, websphere-8, wsadmin

I want to change Web Application's class loader order to PARENT_LAST  using WebSphere Java Administration API.

Enterprise Applications > MyAppEAR  > Manage Modules > MyApp.war

How to get the attribute to set using ConfigService.

Tried the below code which threw

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to javax.management.AttributeList
>       at com.kony.admin.deployment.websphere.KonyWebsphereDeployer.updateArtifact(KonyWebsphereDeployer.java:1854)

```
  AttributeList clList = (AttributeList) configService.getAttribute (session, appDeplID, "modules"); 
  ConfigServiceHelper.setAttributeValue (clList, "classloaderMode", "PARENT_LAST"); 
  attrList.add (new Attribute ("modules", clList));
```

Thanks,
Kusuma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the solution

```
  private void updateArtifactConfig(String appName, DeploymentConfig dc)
  throws DeploymentException {
Session session = new Session();
try {
  ObjectName[] classLoadersId = configService.resolve(session,
      "Deployment=" + appName + "\":ApplicationDeployment:WebModuleDeployment:");

  AttributeList attrList = new AttributeList();
  AttributeList clList = (AttributeList)configService.getAttribute(session, classLoadersId[0],
      "classloader");
  ConfigServiceHelper.setAttributeValue(clList, "mode",
      "PARENT_LAST");
  attrList.add(new Attribute("classloader", clList));
  configService.setAttributes(session, classLoadersId[0], attrList);
  configService.save(session, true);

} catch (Exception ex) {
  LOGGER.error("Not able to update " + appName, ex);
} finally {
  try {
    configService.discard(session);
  } catch (ConfigServiceException csEx) {
    LOGGER.error("Not able to discard updateArtifact " + appName + " session", csEx);
  } catch (ConnectorException cnEx) {
    throw new DeploymentException("Unable to connect to IBM WebSphere Application Server @ "
        + dc.getHostname() + ":" + dc.getPort());
  }
}
```

}